# Keep getting "AttributeError: Read" from pytesseract

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, attributeerror, python-tesseract

I'm trying to take a screen grab with PILLOW and reading text from it using pytesseract but I keep seeing a "AttributeError: read". I've tried to read the documentation and google but haven't found anything.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import PIL

snapShot = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(0, 0, 500, 500)      #takes screenshot and stores it temporarily


pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\venv\Scripts\pytesseract.exe'      #locate pytesseract exe

im = Image.open(snapShot)
text = pyt.image_to_string(im)

print(text)
```

Error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 519, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

Comment: `Image.open` wants to open a file by name.  `snapShot` is not a file name.  It is an image object.  You shouldn't need that line at all.  Just pass `snapShot` to `image_to_string`.  You didn't look at the error very carefully.  That didn't come from pytesseract.  It came frim `Image.open`.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment pointed out the use of 'Image.open()' on a Image object causes the error. Removing this gave another error however 'PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied' which was resolved by installing [the tesseract client](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) on top of the pytesseract package and pointing to it.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import PIL

snapShot = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(0, 0, 500, 500)      #takes screenshot and stores it temporarily


pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract\tesseract.exe'      #default path to tesseract client executable

text = pyt.image_to_string(snapshot)

print(text)
```